# how to know if website is using cookies or not?

Tags: javascript, html, http, cookies

I've a requirement to verify for the website that I need to test.

- Website shall not use cookies

**My question**, How do I find out the **Smartway if any** whether the **entire Website** is really using the cookies or not?

I know a way by which I'll disable the cookies in the browser and then while accessing the website from that browser it should shout out that cookies are not enabled in the browser. But I believe for this I'll have to check each-and-every webpage to confirm whole website is not using cookies.

Comment: Try to place a cookie. If you cannot read it back, the client's agent disabled or cannot handle cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) in your console to read all the cookies accessible from that location.

You could also open up your dev tools and view them there. In Chrome, the cookies can be found in the `application` tab of the dev tools.

[More info](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/manage-data/cookies)

Comment: Application -> Cookies Option in Chrome is straight forward and quick to find out if the website is using cookies or not. I don't have to write any code to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
if (document.cookie != null) {
  alert("Cookies!")
} else {
  alert("No cookies!")
}
```

```html
<!-- YOUR CODE -->
<h1>Note: Stack Overflow dosent let me check document.cookie ):</h1>
```

I think this will work...